# Exception handling in Saxonica URIResolver

Tags: xslt, saxon

I am using saxonica EE version for xslt transformation, and throw an exception from custom URI Resolver class (given below), it is working fine for #include but same not working for #document(),

1. is there anyway we can stop transformation by throwing the exception while resolving document().
2. is it possible to apply URI resolver to document() during the compilation itself(while generating SEF).

public  class CustomURIResolver implements URIResolver {

```
    @Override
    public Source resolve(String href, String base) {
                String formatterOrlookUpKey = getKey(href);
        if (formatterMap.containsKey(formatterOrlookUpKey)) {
            return new StreamSource(new StringReader(formatterMap.get(formatterOrlookUpKey)));
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("did not find the lookup/formatter xsl " + href+" key:"+formatterOrlookUpKey);
        }

    }}
```

XSLT compilation :

```
Processor processor = new Processor(true);
            XsltCompiler compiler = processor.newXsltCompiler();
            compiler.setJustInTimeCompilation(false);
            compiler.setURIResolver(new CigURIResolver(formatterMap));
            XsltExecutable stylesheet = compiler.compile(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xsl)));
            stylesheet.export(destination);
```

Transformation

```
Processor processor = new Processor(true);
        XsltCompiler compiler = processor.newXsltCompiler();
        compiler.setJustInTimeCompilation(true);
            XsltExecutable stylesheet = compiler.compile(new StreamSource(new StringReader(sef)));

        final StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        Serializer out = processor.newSerializer(writer);
        out.setOutputProperty(Serializer.Property.METHOD, "xml");
        out.setOutputProperty(Serializer.Property.INDENT, "yes");
        Xslt30Transformer trans = stylesheet.load30();
        trans.setURIResolver(new CigURIResolver(formatterMap));
        trans.setErrorListener(errorHandler);
        trans.transform(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xml)), out);
        Object obj = out.getOutputDestination();
```

Comment: Do you have a single resolver setup for the XsltCompiler and the Xslt30Transformer? Show us the relevant code where you set up the resolvers and tell us what "not working" exactly means, is your resolver not called, does your exception not stop the XSLT transformation?

Comment: I am using the same URI resolver class but different object  for include and document .. XsltCompiler is working fine, Xslt30Transformer is not stopping the transformation eventhough i threw runtime exception as shown in code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little surprised by the observed effect, and would need a repro to investigate it. But I'm also a bit surprised that you're choosing to throw a RuntimeException, rather than a TransformerException which is what the URIResolver interface declares. If you want to explore this further please raise a support request with runnable code.

The rules for document() are a bit complex because of the XSLT 1.0 legacy of "recoverable errors": you might find that doc() behaves more predictably.

As regards compile-time resolution of doc() calls, Saxon does have an option to enable that, but it doesn't play well with SEF files: generally having external documents in a SEF file gets very messy, especially if for example you have several global variables bound to different parts of the same document.

Comment: thanks Michael, changed URI resolver exception to TransformerException, still transformation not throwing any error.